# Google Cloud Vision API "cannot use connPool"

Tags: go, google-cloud-vision

I'm learning Google Cloud Vision API, but facing some issues. I have completely repeated all the steps from the 'Getting Started' Guide.

1. download/install google cloud SDK
2. activate login credentials using gcloud
3. Set the environment variable GOOGLE_APPLICATION_CREDENTIALS
4. Install the client library

After that I ran [this](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/blob/master/vision/vision_quickstart/main.go) code and got this error when compiling:

```
..\cloud.google.com\go\longrunning\autogen\operations_client.go:166:54: cannot use connPool (type "google.golang.org/api/internal".ConnPool) as type *"google.golang.org/grpc".ClientConn in argument to longrunning.NewOperationsClient

Compilation finished with exit code 2
```

I repeated all the steps over and over and still get this error. Windows 10 is installed on my pc with the latest software updates.
I have NOT changed the code from the tutorial.

Can anyone please tell me why I'm getting this error?

Comment: Can you share Go lang version installed `go version`?

Comment: ```go version go1.15.3 windows/amd64```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue has been fixed.

I just needed to remove conflicting custom imports and re-install Google Vision library.

Well that was a dumb mistake, sorry to bother you.

Comment: Great that the issue has been solved! Can you share more details and steps that you've performed to overcome the problem, thus it can bring a good effort to other community contributors seeking the solution. Also making answer [accepted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) indicates existence of reliable solution.